# Representing a graph in JSON

Tags: json, data-structures, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897956/how-do-you-store-a-directed-acyclic-graph-dag-as-json) question, I'm trying to represent a DAG in JSON. My case includes edges and nodes that contain some data (rather than just strings as in this example). I was thinking of a spec like this:

```
{
    "graph": {
        "a": ["b", "c"],
        "b": ["c"]
        "c"
    },

    "nodes": {
        "a": {
            "name": "Adam"
        },
        "b": {
            "name": "Bob"
        },
        "c": {
            "name": "Caillou"
        }
    },

    "edges": {
        // how to do the same for edges?
        // ie: how to query edges ?
    }
}
```

One idea I had was to make the keys of the edges be the concatenation of the two vertex ids that it connects. For example, `ab`, `ac`, and `bc` are the three edges in this graph. I want to know if there's a more standard way of doing this.

EDIT: This is what I'm thinking of now

```
{
    "graph": {
        "a": {
            "data": {
                // a's vertex data
            },
            "neighbors": {
                "b": {
                    "data": {
                        // data in edge ab
                    }
                },
                "c": {
                    "data": {
                        // data in edge ac
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "b": {
            "data": {
                // b's vertex data
            },
            "neighbors": {
                "c": {
                    "data": {
                        // data in edge bc
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "c": {
            "data": {
                // c's vertex data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since the DAG's edges hold data, they better have their own identifiers, just like the nodes. That is, the json representation should be composed of three components:

1. **Node records:** mapping each node identifier to the node's data.
2. **Edge records:** mapping each edge identifier to the edge's data.
3. **Adjacency lists:** mapping each node identifier to an array of edge identifiers, each corresponds to an edge going out of the node.

   ```
   DAG = {
     "adjacency": {
       "a": ["1", "2"],
       "b": ["3"]
     },
     "nodes": {
       "a": {
         // data
       },
       "b": {
         // data
       },
       "c": {
         // data
       }
     },
     "edges": {
       "1": {
         "from": "a", "to": "b",
         "data": {
           // data
         }
       },
       "2": {
         "from": "a", "to": "b",
         "data": {
           // data
         }
       },
       "3": {
         "from": "b", "to": "c",
         "data": {
           // data
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will consider doing this, but that means I will have to somehow generate edge ids, which would be kinda annoying if I manually want to create this graph. What do you think of my edit ?

Comment: @Carpetfizz, combining the two vertex ids into an edge id is definitely legit. Go for it.

Comment: Great, thanks! Will still accept you since you gave a valid answer. I wanted to model mine like networkx which is a python library

Comment: What is the purpose of the adjacency list? Can't the same information be gathered from the node list plus the edge "from" property?

Answer (score 17):

Turns out there are standards that are trying to emerge for this sort of thing.  I recently had to look these up for a project of my own.  You might be interested in http://jsongraphformat.info/ for example, or one of the peer projects it references on its website.  Goals include trying to represent in JSON anything you can represent in the DOT language (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)).

Answer (score 6):

[json-ld](https://json-ld.org) was made for this. It has a semi-steep learning curve, but it is a robust way to represent graph data in json.